# Как переписать curl запрос PHP в чистый JS?

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5, curl

```html
<?php
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $phone = $_GET['phone'];
    $offer_id = '6'; 
    $api_key = 'fgf44d'; 
    $country_code = 'RO'; 
    $base_url = 'https://land1.ab'; 
    $price = '160'; 
    $referrer = 'super.com'; 
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    
    const API_URL = "https://api.adcombo.com/api/v2/order/create/";
    const API_KEY = "fgf44d";
    
    $isCurlEnabled = function(){
        return function_exists('curl_version');
    };
    if (!$isCurlEnabled) {
        echo "<pre>";
        echo "pls install curl\n";
        echo "For *unix open terminal and type this:\n";
        echo 'sudo apt-get install curl && apt-get install php-curl';
        die;
    }
    
    $args = array(
    
     'api_key' => $api_key,
     'name' => $name,
     'phone' => $phone,
     'offer_id' => $offer_id,
     'country_code' => $country_code,
     'base_url' => $base_url,
     'price' => $price,
     'referrer' => $referrer,
     'ip' => $ip
    
    );
    
    $url = API_URL.'?'.http_build_query($args);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    ));
    curl_close($curl);
```

Есть такой php код. Поля name и phone шли из полей формы на сайте html и перебрасывались на страницу .php 
Как это все переписать на чистый JS, чтобы вставить в html как < script >?

Comment: АПИ `https://api.adcombo.com/api/v2/order/create/` ваше?

Comment: Нет, это сторонний сайт

Comment: Тогда, если вы перепишете на js и будете вызывать в браузере, то у вас будет ошибка CORS.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko выходит это гиблый вариант в целом?

Comment: Ну если CORS будет разрешен на сервере, т.е. если вы имеете возможность настраивать веб сервер, то все норм.

Comment: Если нет возможности настроить CORS на стороннем сайте то да, вариант на js работать не будет.